# MariaDB: Can't reference parent table in dependent subquery -- same query works in MySQL

Tags: mariadb

Running the below query in MySQL 8 produces the rows you see below:

| data |
| --- |
| {"Artist": [{"Name": "AC/DC"}]} |
| {"Artist": [{"Name": "Accept"}]} |

However, running the same query in MariaDB `10.11.2` gives the following error:

```
[42S22][1054] (conn=27) Unknown column 'Album.ArtistId' in 'where clause'
```

Does anyone happen to know why this is, and if there is a way to work around it?

Thank you.

---

**DBFiddle Links:**

- MySQL 8: https://dbfiddle.uk/X3-KOufe
- MariaDB: https://dbfiddle.uk/l2mFHJi7

---

```sql
with Artist(ArtistId, Name) as (
    select 1 as ArtistId, 'AC/DC' as Name
    union all
    select 2 as ArtistId, 'Accept' as Name
), Album(AlbumId, Title, ArtistId) as (
    select 1 as AlbumId, 'For Those About To Rock We Salute You' as Title, 1 as ArtistId
    union all
    select 2 as AlbumId, 'Balls to the Wall' as Title, 2 as ArtistId
)

select
    json_object(
            'Artist',
            (
                select
                    json_arrayagg(j)
                from
                    (
                        select
                            json_object('Name', `Name`) as `j`
                        from
                            (
                                select
                                    `Artist`.*
                                from
                                    `Artist`
                                where
                                        -- !!! ERROR HAPPENS HERE IN MARIADB !!!
                                        `Album`.`ArtistId` = `Artist`.`ArtistId`
                            ) as `Artist`
                    ) as `j`
            )
        ) as data
from
    (
        select
            `Album`.*
        from
            `Album`
    ) as `Album`;
```

Comment: If I were to be asking this question, I'd reverse it - Why in the world would MySQL `NOT` throw an error in `select table1.* from table1 where table1.id = table2.id` when it doesn't include a join with table2 prior to the where clause? Anyway, what output are you seeking from that dataset? Is the output you show in your question the output you are seeking?

Comment: To get the results in your query, you could do https://dbfiddle.uk/OfWs3Iap (MariaDB) and https://dbfiddle.uk/KLLCpKiz (MySQL). The query would be simplified to `select json_object('Artist', json_array(j)) from (select json_object('Name', `Name`) as j from Artist) x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work, but here's how you can achieve what you want, with a minor change.

You need to do the join one level up at the same level as you do the json_arrayagg, then it works:

```sql
with Artist(ArtistId, Name) as (
    select 1 as ArtistId, 'AC/DC' as Name
    union all
    select 2 as ArtistId, 'Accept' as Name
), Album(AlbumId, Title, ArtistId) as (
    select 1 as AlbumId, 'For Those About To Rock We Salute You' as Title, 1 as ArtistId
    union all
    select 2 as AlbumId, 'Balls to the Wall' as Title, 2 as ArtistId
)
select
    json_object(
        'Artist',
        (
            select
                json_arrayagg(`ArtistJson`.`j`)
            from
            (
                select
                    json_object('Name', `Name`) as `j`,
                    `ArtistAlias`.`ArtistId` -- Return the join column here
                from
                (
                    select
                        `Artist`.*
                    from
                        `Artist`
                ) as `ArtistAlias`
            ) as `ArtistJson`
            -- So that you can use it here
            where `AlbumAlias`.`ArtistId` = `ArtistJson`.`ArtistId` 
        )
    ) as data
from
(
    select
        `Album`.*
    from
        `Album`
    
) as `AlbumAlias`;
```